# Getting the error: Procedure created with compilation errors.. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CustomerTotal  
(pl_cname s5.saleinv.cname%TYPE) 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(totalprice) FROM s5.saleinv WHERE UPPER(cname) = UPPER(pl_cname);
END CustomerTotal;
```

When I enter `SHOW ERROR`, it tells me `identifier 's5.saleinv' must be declared`. s5.saleinv is my table name.

Comment: When I enter SHOW ERROR.. it tells me identifier 's5.saleinv' must be declared.. s5.saleinv is my table name

Comment: In Oracle, a stored procedure has to put the results somewhere.  You cannot just run a `select`.

Comment: What user are you logged in as?  Are you certain that user has access to `s5.saleinv` via a direct grant (not via a role)?  That's necessary to create a definer's rights procedure that accesses the table.  If your intention is just to return a value to the caller, you probably want a function not a procedure, you want to select the `sum(totalprice)` into a local variable, and then you can return that variable.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CustomerTotal(v_cname IN s5.saleinv.cname%TYPE,
v_sum IN NUMBER) 
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT SUM(totalprice) 
   INTO v_sum FROM s5.saleinv WHERE UPPER(cname) = UPPER(v_cname);
END CustomerTotal;
/        -- Iam still getting the same error